# Can someone tell me where to read of the topic lidar camera cross calibration

Tags: camera, calibration, lidar

I am a beginner to this topic and am not able to find any of the useful resources.

Answer (score 0):

Here is 3 examples, two of them use ROS, third is Matlab implementation:

[Link to github, ROS](https://github.com/ankitdhall/lidar_camera_calibration)

[Link to github, Matlab](https://github.com/YechengLyu/WPI-LiDAR-Camera-Calibration-Toolbox)

[Link to github, ROS](https://github.com/agarwa65/lidar_camera_calibration)